# using Git Bash for Conda virtual environment

Tags: conda, git-bash

I am brand new to coding, in doing my pre-work for a coding course I've been asked to install Conda virtual environment.  I can do it thru Anaconda prompt but doing it thru Bash gives me an error (the course wants in done thru Bash)

$ conda --version
bash: conda: command not found

Answer (score 1):

this helped a lot
https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/setting-up-conda-in-git-bash/534473

Basically, you need to source the `conda.sh` that is located (typically) in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\etc\profile.d`

just edit your .bash_profile to include `. /c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`